# Short line in math expression?

Tags: math-operators

I have a mathematical terminology, and I can not do it correctly using LaTex.

The origin form is in picture below:
[image]

My version is: 
[image]

The main problem is the line between a number and the word simplex. 
Can you help fix it, and provide the correct LaTex expression?

Comment: It looks like you're typing `$2-complex$`. Try `2-\textit{complex}` instead. A general recommendation: Don't use math mode if all you need to do is to write something in italics. (The hyphen/dash character should not be rendered as a minus symbol, right?) Use math mode for formulas.

Comment: You should use `$k$-simplex` and `$2$-complex`, because `-complex` is not math. If you want it in italics, then type `\textit{$2$-complex}`.

Comment: @egreg \textit{2-complex} works for me. tks

Comment: @user2262504 It's wrong: the number should be upright.

Comment: Or use `$2$\nobreakdash-\textit{complex}` for preventing a change of line in `2-`. `\nobreakdash` belongs to `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to collect the different approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l @{\qquad\qquad} l}
  Code                        & Output              \\
  \midrule
  \verb|$2-complex$|          & $2-complex$         \\[1ex]
  \verb|$2$-complex|          & $2$-complex         \\[1ex]
  \verb|2-\textit{complex}|   & 2-\textit{complex}  \\[1ex]
  \verb|\textit{$2$-complex}| & \textit{$2$-complex}\\[1ex]
  \verb|\textit{2-complex}|   & \textit{2-complex}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I believe egreg's approach is the correct one.